# Variation of a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have to find the variation of the following functional:

[image]

There are two conditions a > 0 and b > 0.
The question is "find the differential equation with respect to x(t), so that the functional is minimized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y(\tau) = x(\tau) + \varepsilon \eta(\tau)$ where $\eta(\tau)$ is an arbitrary but twice differentiable function.  Then
$$
S[y(\tau)]=\int_0^t a \left(\dot{x}(\tau)+\varepsilon \dot{\eta}(\tau)\right)^2 + b\left(\ddot{x}(\tau)+\varepsilon \ddot{\eta}(\tau)\right)^2 + c(x(\tau)+\varepsilon \eta(\tau))^4 d\tau.
$$
Take the derivative wrt to $\varepsilon$ and let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, yielding
$$
\nabla_\eta S[x(\tau)] = \int_0^t 2a\dot{x}(\tau)\dot{\eta}(\tau) + 2 b \ddot{x}(\tau)\ddot{\eta}(\tau) + 4 c x(\tau)^3\eta(\tau) d\tau.
$$
This is the directional/Gateaux derivative of $S[]$ wrt $\eta$ evaluated at $x$.

Are you optimizing the functional?  The idea is that if you are at $x$ and take a step $\varepsilon$ in the direction $\eta$ in the appropriate space of functions, you are evaluating the value of moving from $x$ towards $y$. Setting $\nabla_\eta S[x^*]=0$ means that there are no directions away from $x^*$ that locally improve $S$.  Do you have initial conditions, or other constraints?

Comment: The question is "find the differential equation with respect to x(t), so that the functional is minimized"

Comment: What sign is $c$?  If $c>0$, it feels like $x(\tau) = 0$ must be the solution, which achieves a global value of zero. Any other twice-differentiable $x$ will given strictly positive values of one or more of the terms of the integrand.

Comment: If $c<0$, just take $x(\tau)$ to be an arbitrary and positive constant $\bar{x}$.  The dot and double dot terms are zero, so you get $tc\bar{x}<0$, and you can make the functional as negative as you want, meaning the problem is unbounded below and a minimizer does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
x_1 = x\\
x_2 = \dot x\\
x_3 = \ddot x
$$

$X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ we have

$$
S = \int _0^t (a x_2^2+b x_3^2+c x_1^4)d\tau\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \dot X = A X
$$

with $A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\\end{array}\right)$

Now considering the lagrangian

$$
L = \int _0^t (a x_2^2+b x_3^2+c x_1^4+\lambda_1(t)(\dot x_1-x_2)+\lambda_2(t)(\dot x_2-x_3))d\tau
$$

and using the Euler-Lagrange equations we get at

$$
\cases{\dot\lambda_1 = 4cx_1^3\\ \dot\lambda_2 +\lambda_1 = 2 a x_2\\ \lambda_2=2bx_3}
$$

and after substitution we obtain the following differential equation:

$$
bx''''-a x''+2c x^3=0
$$

Comment: They are Lagrange multipliers.